# Issues running github package specifically with Tensorflow on python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, command-prompt, python-3.6

I am running python 3.6 (32-bit) on my Windows 10 pro (64-bit). I have been using Command prompt to try and install the packages to get this up and running but am not having much luck. Just began coding yesterday, would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

This is the error message coming up in command prompt when i try and run the git hub file:

```
C:\Users\sek53\Desktop\BatchEffectRemoval-master\BatchEffectRemoval-master\src>python train_MMD_ResNet.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(__file__)])
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
  raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 
66, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-
 packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
 _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in 
swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_MMD_ResNet.py", line 8, in <module>
    import keras.optimizers
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in 
<module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, 
in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
 ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow' [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: I am not sure Tensorflow can work at all on 32bit Python. Any reason you can't use 64bit?